# CSS is not changing through calling JS in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, dom

my JS code is bellow:

```
// JavaScript Document

function bubbleColor() {

    if($("#Checkbox1").is(":checked") && $("#Checkbox2").is(":checked")) 
    {
        $(".bubble").css("background-color", "red");

    }
}
var el = document.getElementById(".bubble");
el.onclick = bubbleColor;
```

And my targeted HTML:

```
       <div id="circle" class="bubble">
                    <p class="circle_text">

                        #6

                    </p>
                </div>

 <br/><br/>

        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox1" name="Checkbox1"/> Answer one <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox2" name="Checkbox2"/> Answer two <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox3" name="a3"/> Answer three <br/>
```

Desired output:

When somebody checks [selects] both the Checkbox1 and Checkbox2, the #6 background should be Red color.

Problem:

The code does not seem to work.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming you are using jquery (as you are changing css with jquery)

The behaviour you describe in your question implies that changing the checkbox should trigger a verification, so why do you attach the bubbleColor function to clicking on the .bubble div?

Try something like this:

```
// Alternatively you could use a class to select the checkboxes
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(bubbleColor);
```

Ofcourse ideally you should change your function to remove the red color if you uncheck the boxes:

```
function bubbleColor() {
  if ($("#Checkbox1").is(":checked") && $("#Checkbox2").is(":checked")) {
    $(".bubble").css("background-color", "red");
  } else {
    $(".bubble").css("background-color", "transparent");
  }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sQCcF/2/

Edit:
If what you want is to ensure user only selects 1 option then you should use radio buttons instead of checkboxes, as that is the default behavior:

```
<input type="radio" name="inputname" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="inputname" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="inputname" value="3"/>
```

The name has to be the same for the inputs, but each one will have a different value, selecting one will automatically unselect the other.

Comment: Can be shortened to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/sQCcF/3/)... :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Basically, this is not for verification purpose. Its some kind of alert that warns a user. Actually there are 10 check boxes and I have to make sure if first 2 is selected then the bubble background should be red color.

Comment: I would suggest using radio buttons with the same name instead, ill edit answer with this suggestion

Comment: @cernunnos: The user should select multiple option that is why I choose check box.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is at

```
var el = document.getElementById(".bubble");
```

You are selecting element with ID of .bubble (bubble is a class)

Change it to and check :

```
var el = document.getElementById("circle");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but unfortunately this is not working :(

Comment: Yes it IS working. When you change .bubble to circle as suggested and then check 2 first checkboxes, background goes red.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you attach an event handler for the click event on div with class "bubble".
Then, you use document.getElementById method to select an element but you use as argument the class of that element, not the ID.

For this to work you need to attach the click event handler to checkbox elements.
Something like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    bubbleColor();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace var el = document.getElementById(".bubble");
el.onclick = bubbleColor;

with

$(".bubble").click(bubbleColor) ;

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

HTML

```
<div id="circle" class="bubble">
 <p class="circle_text">
     #6
 </p>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox1" name="Checkbox1" class="chBox"/> Answer one <br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox2" name="Checkbox2" class="chBox" /> Answer two <br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="Checkbox3" name="a3" class="chBox" /> Answer three <br/>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // you can use '.chBox class or input[type='checkbox']'
    $('.chBox').bind('click', function(){
        if($("#Checkbox1").is(":checked") && $("#Checkbox2").is(":checked")) 
        {
            $(".bubble").css("background-color", "red");
        }else{
            $(".bubble").css("background-color", "#fff");
        }    
    });
});
```